# Set value in row based on date input in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Event  | date_begin  |  date_end   |   status   |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| event1 | 10-Nov-2019 | 31-Nov-2019 | Active     |
| event2 | 10-Oct-2019 | 31-OCT-2019 | Not Active |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

User will input event name, date_begin and date_end. Is there any way to make status automatically being set based on the date that have been input by user.?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers, There different types of triggers:

- After update triggers
- Before Update triggers
- After insert triggers
- Before insert triggers
- Before Delete triggers
- After Delete triggers

You can use `After insert` or `Before insert` triggers to set status.
You can get help from this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-types-of-mysql-triggers-with-examples/